# How can I best represent users and the managers they report to within a relational database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

For example, we have `User1, User2, and User3`. Each of these three users reports to `Manager1`, who in turn reports to `Boss1`. All of these individuals are in the `users` table and are uniquely identified by `user_id`. We only must keep track of the current manager for each user in the table.

How would this best be executed? I raise the question because it's essentially a reference to the same table, and I'm hesitant to just add a `manager_id` column to the `users` table because we may be running into a situation like `Boss1`, who may not have a direct manager (I suppose we may choose to make this edge case self referential, e.g. set `Boss1`'s manager to himself).

Just wanted to get some food for thought on designing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know for sure that no user will ever have more than one manager, you could set `Boss1`'s manager to `null`. This would explicitly indicate that he doesn't have any, and would prevent a program that simply walks up the chain of managers from getting into an endless loop.

If you're *not* sure that users will only ever have a single manager and you want to cater to this case, you can create a new `user_manager` table with columns `user_id` and `manager_id`, each being a foreign key to the `users` table and both being part of the primary key. This way, a user with 2 managers will have two records in that table, and `Boss1` will simply have none where he is the `user_id`.

Comment: Besides setting it as null, that's essentially what possibilities I had considered so far. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @JTApps In this case - unless you have other requirements that you haven't mentioned - I think you've covered all the simple solutions. =)

Comment: Sounds great, I'll take the answer and give it a go. Thanks